# iOS Subclass UICollectionViewCell custom init method

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm implementing a custom UICollectionViewCell, and I want to know how to send model data to it so the data can be used to initialize the subviews of the cell.

I register my MyCollectionViewCell by doing..

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

and in the following method, I do...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

MyCollectionViewCell* cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The problem I'm facing is, when a cell isn't in the reuse queue, it initializes a new cell by calling the initWithFrame method (which the documentation confirms should happen). However, I have a custom init method in my MyCollectionViewCell class, which is...

```
-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withData: (NSDictionary*) data;
```

I want my custom initialize method to be called instead. How would I do that? I'm not using any nibs and I'm doing everything programmatically.

If there's no way, and I must use the initWithFrame method instead, how else can I pass model data to my MyCollectionViewCell so that I can initialize the subviews with that data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [cell initData:data] right after you dequeue it? You probably need to re-init the data on dequeued cells, anyway.

Comment: This. If you're reusing a cell, you wouldn't pass initWith... anything to it, so setting up the data should be separate from the init method.

Comment: Except, don't call it initData. Call it configureForData or setData (if data is a property) something. init... methods should only be called on newly allocated objects.

Comment: THat makes sense. After I call setData and pass in my model data, how do I trigger the cell to reload it' UI? Do I call setNeedsLayout and have a -(void) layoutSubviews method in my custom cell?

Comment: Unless you are changing the size of the view dynamically, you won't need/want to lay it out again. Don't forget, at this point the cell is not visible. All you need to do (for example) is setText on your label, with new data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to give your layoutAttributes object a pointer to the data and have the cell grab it from there in its applyLayoutAttributes: method.